# 'Eigen' matrices with static dimension

Tags: c++, eigen

I noticed that 'Eigen' matrices with dynamic dimension are less efficient than the matrices with static dimension. My algorithm uses a lot of matrices which don't need to be resized, so I wanted to use static dimensions, but the dimension is not known in advance and this doesn't work:

```
const size_t n = 3;
Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n> A;
```

Is there a workaround? Perhaps with a macro? (I'm not fluent in C/C++ and I don't know macros yet, sorry if my question is silly).

Comment: That code compiled for me with Visual Studio 2019. But in general, you need to know the size at compile time. There is a little used feature that allows you to define a maximum size, which can be a useful compromise. 

`const size_t max_size = 10;
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::ColMajor, max_size, max_size> A;`

Comment: You can use constexpr instead of const if the value is known during compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in the general case, there is no suitable workaround. C++ is a statically typed language, and the compiler needs to know all types at compilation time. If your code worked, the following would also

```
const size_t n = std::rand();
Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n> A;
```

and `rand()` only gives a random number at run-time, which, at compile-time is unknown.

Moreover, I would not rely too much on the statement that fixed-size matrices lead to faster code execution than dynamic ones. There is an optimization effect, but it pays only for small dimensions. The Eigen help-page states that it should be used "typically up to 4x4, sometimes up to 16x16" but not for larger matrices.

Here are the possibilities for special cases:

- `static const` and `constexpr` tells the compiler that the variable *is* a compile-time expression. You can use it as a placeholder, and this avoids typing the magic number repeatedly:

  ```
  static constexpr size_t n = 3;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n> A;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n> B;
  ```

  But still you can't use that for dynamic numbers.
- The best you can do is when you can boil down your dimensions to a few special cases. Say you want to optimize for dimensions `n=2,3,4`. Then you can wrap up your calculations into a big function template `calculate<n>` and let the compiler explicitly instantiate the few special cases, e.g. by

  ```
  if(n==2)
  {
      calculate<2>();
  }
  else if(n==3)
  {
      calculate<3>();
  }
  ...
  ```

  (There are smarter techniques for this, but this "if-loop" perfectly gives the idea)

  By this, you increase the compilation time by a factor that corresponds to the number of special cases, but the runtime will prossibly be faster. And then, you can choose `n` dynamically at least from the chosen range.

  If you're further interested in this technique, let me know.